# undefined method `flash' for #<ActionDispatch::Request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, flash-message

I have stuff with Ruby on Rails 3

I try this simple code

```
  def index
    flash[:notice] = "ok"
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
    end
  end
```

it does not work

```
NoMethodError in DashboardsController#index
undefined method `flash' for #<ActionDispatch::Request:0x7fee9329a9d0>
```

When I try

```
redirect_to :some_in, :notice => "ok"
```

in other place (in some_controller.rb) and then print this :notice in .erb
I have same error, undefined method `flash'

I'm stuck on this. I used google to search for it but it does not help.

Comment: Are you inheriting from `ApplicationController` which is inheriting from `ActionController::Base`?  For example, does your controller look like: `class DashboardsController < ApplicationController` at the top?

Comment: Are you using the `rails-api` gem by chance?

Comment: For anyone who is using `rails-api`, see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21149689/21115)

Answer (score 3):

In `config/applications.rb` of your app add this

```
config.api_only = false
```

Answer (score 3):

Please include [ActionDispatch::Flash](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Flash.html) middleware into your   config/application.rb file.

```
config.middleware.use ActionDispatch::Flash
```

This may help you.

Answer (score -2):

The `flash[:notice]` will only appear after a `redirect_to` or a `render` (although you will need `flash.now[:notice]`).

The flash is there to provide feedback to the user on the status of an action that is taken by the user. Just rendering an index typically does not fall into this category as it is only displaying data, not showing the result of a user taking an action.

As an example:

```
def create
  @post = Post.new(params[:post])

  respond_to do |format|
    if @post.save
      format.html  { redirect_to(@post,
                    :notice => 'Post was successfully created.') }
    else
      format.html  { render :action => "new" }
    end
  end
end
```

In this case the flash will appear on the Post Show view only if the post has been saved directly.

Comment: I tried all I find in google, but still have `NoMethodError in DashboardsController#index
undefined method 'flash' for #<ActionDispatch::Request:0x7fee9329a9d0>`

Comment: The question asks about `flash` method being undefined, not whether or not it appears. Even if there is no output from `flash[:notice]` calling `flash` should not result in NoMethodError under normal circumstances.