# Rails: Undefined method `flash' for ActionDispatch::Request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-api

I'm trying to write an Ember application in Rails 4, and have decided to go with `rails-api` for the api controllers, while keeping the application controller intact for a few pages that aren't part of the single-page app.  To put it in more concrete terms, here are my controllers:

`app/controllers/application_controller.rb`:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery
end
```

`app/controllers/sample_controller.rb`:

```
class SampleController < ApplicationController
  # my methods
end
```

`app/controllers/api/v1/api_controller.rb`:

```
class Api::V1::ApiController < ActionController::Api
  include ActionController::MimeResponds
end
```

`app/controllers/api/v1/sample_controller.rb`:

```
module Api::V1
  class SampleController < ApiController
    respond_to :json

    # my methods

  end
end
```

My `application.html.slim` contains the following line:

```
== render partial: "flash_msgs" unless flash.blank?
```

The inclusion of which results in the following error:

> undefined method 'flash' for #< ActionDispatch::Request:0x007f99f41d8720 >

Per discussion [on this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8855060/undefined-method-flash-for-actiondispatchrequest), it seems that the culprit could be `rails-api`, but I'm not entirely convinced given the inheritance I've set up. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Not sure but maybe you need to include the `ActionDispatch::Flash` middleware to support the flash. Using:

```
config.middleware.use ActionDispatch::Flash
```

The [docs](https://github.com/rails-api/rails-api#other-middlewares) says:

> ActionDispatch::Flash: Supports the flash mechanism in
>   ActionController.

I hope it helps

Comment: Thanks for that, I wasn't expecting `rails-api` to be so heavy-handed in its removal of middleware, and to only really affect the controllers.

Comment: Thank you! I got the same problem with gem `api-pagination` and it fixed it!

Comment: With the changes in the gem http://stackoverflow.com/a/23053260/827770 is the correct answer.

Comment: This goes in application.rb, "and if you don't know, now you know"

Comment: @QaiserWali That's not entirely accurate. The answers below make assumptions about your application (they add back the full stack of middleware or change what's considered "navigational") that aren't always accurate. This answer is still correct for the original use case.

Comment: What if I don't want the flash middleware? Is there a way to remove the Flash mechanism?

Answer (score 34):

See: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/issues/2775

Inside devise.rb change

```
config.navigational_formats = ['*/*', :html]
```

to:

```
config.navigational_formats = [:json]
```

or just [ ]

Comment: For anyone using the excellent `devise_token_auth` instead plain vanilla `devise`, you'll need to create this file at `config/initializers/devise.rb`.

Comment: Thanks Aaron. For `devise_token_auth` also wrap it in `Devise.setup do |config| ... end`

Comment: Hi, I used the [] instead of [:json]. There are many differences between API only rails app ?

Answer (score 32):

If you're like me and creating an API on top of an existing application, you can add this to your config/application.rb file:

`config.api_only = false`

Comment: It should be noted that this option will add back *all* of the middleware that `rails-api` removes. While this may be what you're looking for, just something to be aware of.

Comment: Why are people upvoting this, I have no idea. You've just turned your rails-api app into a rails app.

Comment: @gangelo My answer was directed at folks not using `rails-api`. Rails handles this a lot better now.

Answer (score 0):

well, in my case my API mode rails app I had this code in one of my controller:

```
protect_from_forgery with: :null_session, if: Proc.new { |c| c.request.format == 'application/json' }
```

due to which [handle_unverified_request](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/18707ab17fa492eb25ad2e8f9818a320dc20b823/actionpack/lib/action_controller/metal/request_forgery_protection.rb#L180) was getting called that has this small piece of code `request.flash = nil` which was raising `Undefined method 'flash' for ActionDispatch::Request` for me.

Dealt with it by replacing `protect_from_forgery` with `skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token`