# Rails 4 + Devise + Rails API: undefined method 'flash'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise, rails-api

I have an existing ***Rails 4*** application which uses ***Devise*** and ***Omniauth***. I'm trying to modifying my existing app to develop an ***API***(I mean I will have my web app as it is and also I want an API for mobile app) but I'm having a hard luck.

I'm following the steps that are listed in [**Rails-API**](https://github.com/rails-api/rails-api) under "For already existing apps" section and now I'm getting the below error

```
undefined method `flash' for #<Devise::SessionsController:0x000000098221d0>
```

The error pops at this line `<% unless flash.blank? %>` in `views/devise/sessions/new.html.erb`

I tried putting `config.middleware.use ActionDispatch::Flash` in `/config/application.rb` but the ***error exists***.

I also have `config.api_only = false` in `/config/application.rb`

Below is my code

```
#app/controllers/application_controller.rb
class ApplicationController < ActionController::API
  # Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
  # For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.
  include ActionController::RequestForgeryProtection
  include Pundit
  include ActionController::Serialization
  include ActionView::Layouts
  include ActionController::ImplicitRender
  protect_from_forgery with: :null_session

  ----some other code------
end
```

--------xxxxxx-----------

```
#/config/application.rb
require File.expand_path('../boot', __FILE__)

require 'rails/all'

# Require the gems listed in Gemfile, including any gems
# you've limited to :test, :development, or :production.
Bundler.require(*Rails.groups, :default, :assets, Rails.env)



module SampleApp
  class Application < Rails::Application
    # Settings in config/environments/* take precedence over those specified here.
    # Application configuration should go into files in config/initializers
    # -- all .rb files in that directory are automatically loaded.

    # Set Time.zone default to the specified zone and make Active Record auto-convert to this zone.
    # Run "rake -D time" for a list of tasks for finding time zone names. Default is UTC.
    # config.time_zone = 'Central Time (US & Canada)'

    # The default locale is :en and all translations from config/locales/*.rb,yml are auto loaded.
    # config.i18n.load_path += Dir[Rails.root.join('my', 'locales', '*.{rb,yml}').to_s]
    # config.i18n.default_locale = :de

    # For Custom Error Handling
    config.exceptions_app = self.routes

    config.middleware.use ActionDispatch::Flash

    # To use rails default middleware for api
    config.api_only = false

    config.generators do |g|
        g.test_framework :rspec,
          :fixtures => true,
          :view_spec => false,
          :helper_specs => false,
          :routing_specs => false,
          :controller_specs => true,
          :request_specs => true
        g.fixture_replacement :factory_girl, :dir => "spec/factories"
    end
  end
end
```

-------xxxxxxx-------

```
#routes.rb
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  devise_for :admin_users, ActiveAdmin::Devise.config
  ActiveAdmin.routes(self)
  # TODO add staging/dev password lock to site
  # if Rails.env.staging?
  #   mount Lockup::Engine, at: '/lockup'
  # end

  # TODO come back and fix so admin user (active admin) and regular user can be logged in at same time
  get '/', to: 'users#index', constraints: lambda { |request| request.env['warden'].user && request.env['warden'].user.role == 'admin' }
  #root to: 'visitors#index'

  devise_for :users, :controllers => { :registrations => "registrations", :omniauth_callbacks => "users/omniauth_callbacks" }

  devise_scope :user do
    root to: "devise/sessions#new"
  end

  namespace :api do
    namespace :v1  do
      devise_for :users
    end
  end
  #some other unnecessary routes
end
```

***Question:***

The [**Rails-API**](https://github.com/rails-api/rails-api) says this

> If you want to use the Rails default middleware stack (avoid the
>   reduction that rails-api does), you can just add config.api_only =
>   false to config/application.rb file.

Since I have included `config.api_only = false` to `config/application.rb` and considering the fact that `ActionDispatch::Flash` ships with ***Rails default***, why I'm getting that error? What do I need to get rid of that?

Comment: Did you already try this suggestiion? http://stackoverflow.com/a/21149689/981183

Comment: @KMRakibulIslam I just tried it, the result is the same error.

Answer (score 13):

I tried a lot of suggestions before I boiled it down to these steps. It worked for me. Hope this helps.

Add the following lines in `config/routes.rb`:

```
devise_for :users, defaults: { format: :json }
```

Add the following lines in `config/initializers/devise.rb`:

```
config.navigational_formats = [:json]
```

Add the following lines in `config/application.rb`:

```
config.api_only = true
config.middleware.use ActionDispatch::Flash
```

Comment: Actually, it is fixed for me without 'config.middleware.use ActionDispatch::Flash'

Comment: But had to remmove navigational formats entirely:

config.navigational_formats = []

Comment: I needed all of these things. I have been banging my head against this for three hours. I wish I could buy you a box of chocolates. xoxoxo

Comment: it doesn't work for me. I need to use config.navigational_formats = []. How can solve if I need navigational format?

Comment: I don't think adding back "config.middleware.use ActionDispatch::Flash" is the way to go. Flash messages aren't needed in the API. It may "solve" the problem - but it's not the right way to go.

Answer (score 1):

Devise will only try to set the Flash if it thinks you are expecting your answer back in HTML.

I suspect - the only issue is - that when you called the API you didn't pass in the following headers:

```
"Accept": "application/json"
```

Answer (score -4):

If you try the answer above and still get that same error, try the following.

1. Restart your rails server

If error still persists:

2. In the `application.rb` file change the line `config.api_only = true` that you just added to false:

   ```
   config.api_only = false
   ```

Comment: Turning off `api_only` might resolve the errors but completely defies the purpose of the original post, which is creating an api-only app.