# Use ActionDispatch::Flash on middleware rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, recaptcha

I'm a newbie in Ruby and I'm trying to integrate google re-captcha gem on my Rails application https://github.com/ambethia/recaptcha/.

It works well on localhost, but in production throws this error:

*ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `**flash**' for Node ID: franchises_form Parent: root Children: 0 Total Nodes: 1:FranchisesFormWidget):*

```
119:         </input>
120:       </div>                                
121: 
122:       <%= recaptcha_tags %>
123: 
124:       </br><small>bla bla bla</small>
```

I've been searching on the web, and all the solutions suggest using

```
config.middleware.use ActionDispacth::Flash
```

The problem is that I don't really know where to introduce it. I tried at application.rb, at the recaptcha config file, and at FranchisesFormWidget, which calls the gem's methods for displaying the recaptcha form.

In application.rb I've got references to middleware management:

```
class Refinery::Resources::Engine
  initializer 'delete rack cache' do |app|
    app.config.middleware.delete Rack::Cache
  end
end
class Refinery::Images::Engine
  initializer 'delete rack cache' do |app|
    app.config.middleware.delete Rack::Cache
  end
end
```

So, for example, I added this:

```
class FranchisesFormWidget
  initializer 'use action dispatch flash' do |app|
    app.config.middleware.use ActionDispatch::Flash
  end
end
```

But gives me another error (which I don't remember).
What I am doing wrong? What must I do?

Answer (score 0):

Their documentation (found here: https://www.rubydoc.info/github/ambethia/recaptcha/master/file/README.md#rails-installation) show no configuration for a rails project beyond adding the gem to your gem file and using your api key. It should work out of the box.

If you are using Rails as an API it does not configure the ActionDispatch::Flash and you will have to configure that in your application.rb. You can follow some suggestions on this thread [Rails: Undefined method `flash' for ActionDispatch::Request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19600905/rails-undefined-method-flash-for-actiondispatchrequest)

Comment: This answer would be much more helpful if it explained **how** to configure it.